# asp.net core 2.2 SDK - upgraded from 2.1 - cannot update projects or create new projects

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I had the 2.1 sdk installed on my pc, all of my projects worked fine, and I decided to install the 2.2 sdk and migrate my projects to that, and read the how-to here:  [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio-code)

I could not get the build to work after modifying the csproj, so I uninstalled ALL versions of the SDK and runtime, and then only installed the 2.2 SDK.

Typing:

> dotnet --list-sdks

shows

**2.2.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]**

So it seems installed properly.
I created a new project with

> dotnet new mvc

and it creates the files.

But when I try to build:

> dotnet build

I get this:

**C:\test\test.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.**

I finally tested on a clean installation of Windows, installed the SDK, and everything works and builds properly there - so there's something "dirty" with an old configuration or setting somewhere.

I tried uninstalling the SDK, removing all leftovers in Program Files/dotnet, USERPROFILE/.dotnet, nuget package directory, etc. but still have the same issue.
Any ideas?  I do not wish to reinstall windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to change the MSBuildSDKsPath environment variable to "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.102\Sdks".  Building now works.